# Case expression in Erlang escript

Tags: linux, erlang

I am testing my erlang escript, the content of escriptis this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env escript
main([Action]) ->
    case Action of
        start -> start();
        stop -> stop()
    end;
main(_) ->
    usage().

usage() ->
    io:format("usage: factorial integer\n"),
    halt(1).

start() -> io:format("Start.~n").
stop() -> io:format("Stop.~n").
```

But when I try to run the escript, I got this problem:

```
./escript start
escript: exception error: no case clause matching "start"
```

What caused this problem? Is the format of argument wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command line arguments are passed as strings to `main/1`, not atoms, so you need to match `"start"` and `"stop"`, not `start` and `stop`:

```
...
main([Action]) ->
    case Action of
        "start" -> start();
        "stop" -> stop()
    end;
...
```

---

Unless your actual code is more complicated/different, you can also match `["start"]` and `["stop"]` in the function clause directly:

```
main(["start"]) -> start();
main(["stop"]) -> stop();
main(_) ->
    usage().
```

This will call `usage()` for `./escript foo` as well while your original script would crash, which may or may not be what you want.